# android internal storage

Tags: android, storage, internal

I want to make an application to be able to save files on sdcard and on device (files saved on device must be available to gallery and other applications). Where should I save these files on device, so files should be public? Application must support Android 2.1. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

> Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage. Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally think you should try to keep the number of files on the internal storage to a minimum. Normally on mobiles, the internal memory is quite limited so I'd recommend to try not to safe files locally

Answer (score 0):

i had your same problem and i solved this way:

when external memory is not available (that's my first choice) ,i use internal memory using getCacheDir as starting path, this way only your application can access those files.

next, when i need to see that files on gallery, i use a contentprovider to obtain access to the file, look at this answer i wrote that solved my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13935210/1716620